# CS50 week 4 - Filter less - sepia doesn't work for 3x3

Tags: c, cs50

Can someone tell me why the code doesnt work in 3x3 images, but it does work with 4x4 and single pixel? Everything seems to be correct, and I checked a lot of codes in google and stack overflow and they are similar. These are the results I get from check50:

:) sepia correctly filters single pixel

:( sepia correctly filters simple 3x3 image

expected "100 89 69\n100...", not "100 89 69\n100..."

:( sepia correctly filters more complex 3x3 image

expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "25 22 17\n66 5..."

:) sepia correctly filters 4x4 image

Apparently the problem is in the fourth and seventh line:

Expected Output:

100 89 69

100 89 69

100 89 69

196 175 136

196 175 136

196 175 136

48 43 33

48 43 33

48 43 33

Actual Output:

100 89 69

100 89 69

100 89 69

237 211 165

196 175 136

196 175 136

58 52 40

48 43 33

48 43 33

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
int sepiaRed;
int sepiaGreen;
int sepiaBlue;

for(int h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for(int w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        sepiaRed = round (.393 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .769 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .189 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue);
        sepiaGreen = round (.349 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .686 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .168 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue);
        sepiaBlue = round (.272 * image[h][w].rgbtRed + .534 * image[h][w].rgbtGreen + .131 * image[h][w].rgbtBlue);

        if(sepiaBlue > 255)
        {
            sepiaBlue = 255;
        }
        if(sepiaGreen > 255)
        {
            sepiaGreen = 255;
        }
        if(sepiaRed > 255)
        {
            sepiaRed = 255;
        }

        image[h][w].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
        image[h][w].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
        image[h][w].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
    }
}
return;
}
```

(please keep in mind I´m new to programming, 16 years old and english is not my first lenguage)

Comment: Check50 should contain a bit more details about the failed tests. AFAIR there is part of the test data available as well. You need to understand in which way your result differs from expected result. Your copy only contains the first few characters.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks, I didn't know I could check everything, I edited the post with the whole results

Comment: I don't see any explanation for the program presented getting most pixels right but two very far wrong.  I am inclined to suspect a problem with the test.  Perhaps the test input has been corrupted, for example.